# Why doesn't nightwatch pickup my browser configuration

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch for testing a web site. Below is my configuration file. I want to use phantomjs as the browser so it can be run without open a browser. But when I run the tests with `nightwatch -c integration-tests/nightwatch.json` command, it always open my chrome browser. And I tried to modify the value for `browserName` and found out that whatever I put in doesn't have any effect. Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

```
{
  "src_folders": [
    "./integration-tests/tests"
  ],
  "output_folder": "./integration-tests/reports",
  "custom_commands_path": "",
  "custom_assertions_path": "",
  "page_objects_path": "",
  "globals_path": "",
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": false
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launch_url": "http://localhost:9091",
      "selenium_port": 9515,
      "selenium_host": "localhost",
      "default_path_prefix": "",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": false,
        "path": ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "phantomjs.binary.path" :"node_modules/phantomjs",
        "phantomjs.cli.args" : []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the userAgent that PhantomJS was reporting.

```
{
  "src_folders": [
    "./integration-tests/tests"
  ],
  "output_folder": "./integration-tests/reports",
  "custom_commands_path": "",
  "custom_assertions_path": "",
  "page_objects_path": "",
  "globals_path": "",
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": false
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launch_url": "http://localhost:9091",
      "selenium_port": 9515,
      "selenium_host": "localhost",
      "default_path_prefix": "",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": false,
        "path": ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "phantomjs.binary.path" :"node_modules/phantomjs",
        "phantomjs.cli.args" : [],
        "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> **settings {object}**
>
> *userAgent* defines the user agent sent to server when the web page requests resources.
>
> Source: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html

If you need more examples:

```
// Mac Chrome 46
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"

// Windows Chrome 46
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"

// Mac Firefox 42.0
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"

// Windows Firefox 42.0
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"

// PhantomJS 2.0
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.0.0 Safari/538.1"
```

Comment: I tried to add "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36" in my configuration file but it still launch a browser.